# DNS name appended with 445 port in URL

Tags: oracle, apache, spring-mvc, https, httpwebrequest

I have a problem in request and responses in a Spring MVC application.

When I hit https://test.abc.com/AppName/security.do in a browser. response url is coming like https://test.abc.com:455/AppName/security.do

In Response Headers Content-Location: **https://test.abc.com:455**/AppName/security.do

Because of the port appended, application is not accessable. At what stage I can remove or redirect test.abc.com:445 to test.abc.com.

Application is hosted Oracle Server and uses Apache Webserver before that request will travel through content switch.

Thanks 
Sunny

Answer (score 0):

The solution is, I think, to set [UseCanoncalName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#usecanonicalname) variable in Apache config to *Off*.